# at what minimum length of encoded letter blocks does the average number of binary characters of a prefix code a letter not exceed 1?

Tags: probability, information-theory

Source without memory is generating letters $a,b,c$. $p(a)=\frac{25}{32}$, $p(b)=\frac{4}{32}$, $p(c)=\frac{3}{32}$.
at what minimum length of encoded letter blocks does the average number of binary characters of a prefix code a letter not exceed 1?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Can you please [edit] your post and write your attempts at solving the problem?
If your question is clear and focused on your specific difficulty and you show your effort in solving the problem, it's more likely to get good and helping answers. By the way, take the opportunity to take the [Tour], if you haven't done it already. See also some tips on [ask], on [formatting help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and on writing down equations using [LaTeX / MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020).

Comment: Maybe it worth posting your question in the Electrical Engineering section. Signal processing students would certainly know the answer by heart